# Pseudolocale Not found in phone system settings

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I followed the instructions as specified in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/pseudolocales.

I can't seem to find English [XA] anywhere in the list of supported languages in my phone. Is every phone supposed to support it?

Comment: What smartphone are you using?

Comment: @Aldan Samsung Galaxy s9+

Comment: Check this [link](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/04/19/pseudo-localization-testing-in-android/)

Comment: Have you solved your issue?